# React - How to change state using media queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, media-queries, state

I want to know how can I change the state of a class using media queries? For example, the initial state of my state is false, how can I change to true when the screen is higher than 900px

Comment: There is a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411993/react-hook-only-listen-to-window-width-size-change

Comment: https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/ is an article about creating a useWindowSize hooks that puts the screen width/height in state. You could modify this or use this useWindowSize in another custom hook to do what you are trying to.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an event listener to a `useEffect` hook update your state accordingly. For example:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isGreaterThan900px, setIsGreaterThan900px] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      if (window.innerWidth > 900) {
        setIsGreaterThan900px(true);
      } else {
        setIsGreaterThan900px(false);
      }
    }

    handleResize();

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>is greater than 900 px: {isGreaterThan900px ? "true" : "false"}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please show me an example using class components